# How to allow ink in a protected worksheet?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2003 worksheet with protection enabled being used for data entry on tablet pcs. I'd like to allow users to fill in the contents of the worksheet using ink (and then converting to text), but the ink writing and drawing toolbar is disabled when the worksheet is protected. Is it possible to protect the worksheet and allow ink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but checking the "Edit Objects" option in the Protect Sheet dialog solved my problem. The equivalent vba was `Worksheet.Protect "password" DrawingObjects:=false`.

Comment: There's no problem with answering your own question here.  It shows you're still working the problem and trying to solve it.  Good question, and good answer. :)

Comment: +1 ... this solves another problem as well: in protected cells a comment is not automatically displayed when the mouse is moved over it. Checking the "Edit Objects" property will do the trick.